# Choose interface implementation in universal app depending on platform

Tags: c#, mvvm

In my universal app I have a MainViewModel that I share between both the windows and the Phone projects.
Depending on what project is run, I would like the MainViewModel to implement a different interface. Lets say these are my two classes and the interface that they both implements:

```
 public class PhotoPhone : IPhotograph
    {
        //some methods
    }

    public class PhotoWin : IPhotograph
    {
        //some methods
    }

    public interface IPhotograph
    {
        //some signatures
    }
```

And here is my MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        private IPhotograph _phot;

        public MainViewModel(IPhotograph photo)
        {
               // Depending on what platform is running
               //I want the proper implementation
        }
    }
```

But how can I make my MainViewModel implement the correct implementation of IPhotograph? I'm thinking that maybe some code should be added to my App.Xaml file. Is this maybe the wrong way to go about this issue? I would like to learn the proper way by following MVVM as far as possible.

Comment: Why not just implement the class with the same name, in each project (not in the shared code pseudo project)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your asking here, could you try rephrasing "how can I make my MainiewModel implement the correct implementation of IPhotograph?" ?

Comment: Ok, As you can see I have two different "versions" of the IPhotgraph. If i run the phone-project, I want my MainViewModel to implement PhotoPhone and if i run the windows-project I want the MainViewModel to implement the other one (PhotWin). So I need a way that lets the MainViewModel know which "version" to implement.

Comment: @Roland Shaw, Do you suggest that I create two classes with same name (ex Photgraph) and put one in each project? Then create an instance of it in the mainViewModel and call its methods from there? Sounds good actually. Does this break any rules of MVVM? Thank you

Comment: I should add that I have created a PCL that i am trying to work with. Which is where I was gonna place my Interface and my two implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Two words: dependency injection. Basically, you want your view model to be as ignorant of the details of phone or desktop/laptop or web environment as the rest of the code, so you need to have a different component handling which implementation of `IPhotograph` is actually instantiated. This component is called the dependency injector; there are a lot of frameworks in .NET for this, like StructureMap, Spring.NET, Ninject, Autofac, Unity, Castle Windsor, and so forth.

In Unity, you'd probably set up a pair of configuration files, one for phone and one for Windows, and register types in those, and in particular register different implementations of `IPhotograph` in each. Then make sure the only part of your application that knows about Unity or any concrete types is the initialization point. Seems like you've already gotten that mostly done, using interfaces for most things.

Comment: Thank you!
DI seems like the way to go. The entry-point in my universal-app is App.Xaml.cs. Im not sure what code to add there in order for my application to know which implementation to use. I will see If I can find a way.