# MVVM Dependency Injection cross-platform

Tags: mvvm

Earlier I wrote this question regarding a way to have my MainViewModel implement an interface depending of what project is running in my Universal App.

[Choose interface implementation in universal app depending on platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593272/universal-app-choose-interface-implementation-depending-on-platform)

I have after this implemented MVVM light which lets me register my VM´s like this:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
```

It also offers the oppurtunity to register a VM with an interface in the CTOR like this:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
```

The setup is as follows:

I have 2 projects, Windows and WindowsPhone.
In my VM, which resides in a PCL I have my MainViewModel that takes an ICameraCaller in the ctor.
The projects both have a class that implements ICameraCaller and depending on which project i run I would like to pass the "right" implementation of the CameraCaller to the CTOR.

So I´ve been told that DI is the way to go. This is a fairly new topic for me and I´ve been stuck for a long time.

To me it sounds like it should be a pretty comman task? To pass an implementation of an interface to a VM depending on which projects is running.

Here is the ctor for the MainViewModel:

```
private ICameraCaller _cameraCaller;

public MainViewModel(ICameraCaller cameraCaller)
{
    _cameraCaller = cameraCaller;
}
```

I do not understand how Its possible for me to register an Interface to my viewmodel in the ViewModelLocator considering that I do not know what implementation that will be used. Even if I did know. I cannot access the Implementations in the other projects. I must be going about this problem all wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: use portable version of mvvm light `MVVMLight.portable`. I also suggest you to use some more advanced `IoC` container - personally I prefer `Ninject` (which also have portable version called `Ninject.Portable`) - it suits all my needs. Get it from `Nuget Package Manager`.

Second - create class called `ViewModelLocator` (different for Windows Phone and Windows Modern) it will act as your so-called `ApplicationCore` (place where dependency injection container sits).

Example:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    private readonly IKernel _dependenciesContainer;

    public ViewModelLocator() 
    {
         _dependenciesContainer = new StandardKernel(new ApplicationKernelModule());
    }

    public MainViewModel Main { get { return _dependenciesContainer.Get<MainViewModel>() } }
}

public class ApplicationKernelModule : NinjectModule
{ 
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ICameraCaller>().To<DesktopCameraCaller>();  
    }
} 

public class DesktopCameraCaller : ICameraCaller
{
     // here lies Windows Modern implementation of camera caller
}
```

In App.xaml add your `ViewModelLocator` as `StaticResource` :

```
<Application
x:Class="YourApp.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:YouNamespace"
xmlns:viewModel="using:ViewModelLocatorNamespace">

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <viewModel:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And in your MainView add binding to proper ViewModel:

```
DataContext={Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}, Path=Main}
```

Repeat exactly same steps for your Windows Phone project but in ApplicationModule make bind to your Windows Phone implementation, example: `Bind<ICameraController>().To<WindowsPhoneCameraController>()`.

What does happen there? You use `Inversion of Control` library called `Ninject` to "bind" interfaces into concrete classes. That means - when you call `IKernel.Get<Type>()` and while creating object `Ninject` see anywhere in constructor `ICameraControl` it will create there new `ModernCameraControl` object. You created `ViewModelLocator` to make simple place to store your "Dependency Injection Resolver" (called IKernel) - so you don't have to use ugly service locator pattern and static reference to `Kernel` everywhere. Of course I described it in simplified version - with `Ninject` you can do other awesome things like scoping (for instance you can register interface to class which would be singleton - same object instation everywhere where binded), you can add conditional logic while class being injected (check `Bind<T>().To<T>().WhenInjectedTo/WhenInjectedExactlyTo`, `Bind<T>().ToMethod(..)` etc.).

Comment: Wow! Thank you for a great answer with example!
Im gonna try this out! .

Comment: @user2915962 feel free to ask if something is not clear or doesn't work

Comment: @user2915962 i answered this question without trying in code and looking at documentation, fixed ;)

Comment: It worked great on both projects! Thank you very much!